# connect sql server JAR file

Tags: java, sql-server, jar

I want to connect with SQLServer2012. I got JRE 7 and sqljdbc4.jar. Connection is ok when I start program using eclipse but when I create JAR file connection cannot be done. What should I change?
sqljdbc4.jar is added to referenced libraries and jre7\lib.

Here is code:

```
        String host = textFieldHost.getText();
        String instantion = textFieldInstation.getText();
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + host + "\\" + instantion + ":1433;databaseName=db";

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, textField.getText(), String.valueOf(passwordField.getPassword()));
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: add the stack trace or the response of executing the jar in post, it could be easy to identify your probs

Comment: how do you run your application? do you run inside a container or it is a standalone Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `sqljdbc4.jar` to your [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) when running your application.
The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches for classes and other resource files. The classpath can be set using either the `-classpath` option when calling a JDK tool (the preferred method) or by setting the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.
For example:

```
java -classpath sqljdbc4.jar;. com.foo.Main
```